# Architecture design feedback on allowing users to dynamically model their tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

We are in the early stages of architecting a new SaaS solution which, as a core design requirement, will allow end-users to dynamically define their data models and how they store, connect data. The best/easiest comparison I can use is Airtable, which provides this type of dynamic nature.

There are MANY threads on the topic of how to build out a model that provides dynamic data modeling such as using the standard EAV model, flat big UDF tables, JSON,etc ...all with their pros/cons.

What we are considering is to provide a structure in which we dynamically create/modify/drop real tables per the user interactions. We'd configure a schema per customer, and then allow them to define their model "on the fly". We understand some of the complexity that goes with this, but are looking to see of others have taken this approach? And what success/failure they have had?

There is no silver-bullet for this problems, but by creating actual tables (small number of rows per table), it does provide us the flexibility to scale horizontal pretty readily, and by using X number server, Y number of databases, and Z number of schemas, it should scale infinitely.

The core questions we have are around issues with # of DDL's (create table, alter table, drop table, etc) executing at the same time and core maintenance/upkeep.

We ultimately need to support tens of thousands of users and hundreds of thousands of tables.
IF you do have experience, we'd love to connect with you for potential consulting arrangements.

Comment: I am not sure if I want to consult on this one. Unless all your users understand databases well, they will come up with horrible data models. Data modeling should not be exposed to the end user. It sounds a bit like nobody knows how the incoming data will be structured, which implies that it will be impossible to query the data and extract useful information. This doesn't sound like anybody will get happy here.

Comment: The data structure a very simple. Again, if you check out Airtable, this is what they provide. A user can define a "tab" like in a spreadsheet, then define the columns, then add data. One key feature airtable allows is that a user can create a link/reference to another tab/table. This is similliar to what we're looking to build...think simple spreadsheet type of functionality.